# Make a square in CSS that occupies remaining space of container

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

I want to make a square div, that takes up the remaining size of a container. How can I do this with CSS?

**Specifically:**

1. make a div have a 1:1 aspect ratio (aka a square)
2. make the divs width & height = to the dimension that has less space

**Here's a picture that makes it clear:**

[image]

**Note:**
I am aware of the answers & method using a container component with `padding-bottom: 100%;`. This is not an acceptable solution since it fails #2 (doesn't switch depending on what dimension constrains the square).

**Solutions that don't work:**

- just using flex: https://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/RjMQEQ
- using flex & aspect ratio container: https://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/bYvLOO

Comment: if padding fails, can you share your HTML structure and CSS used and tried so far. A screenshot is useless but for a job to be done.

Comment: .... i have a CSS  answer ... that works, but not knowing where you failed , where would i be helping and not doing your job ;) ... ?

Comment: G-Cyr, I explain why padding fails in my question. It only allows you to set an aspect ratio based on one dimension - either width or height.

Comment: @G-Cyr - I don't see how it would be helpful to add a JSFiddle that just has  two divs in HTML. Similarly, it's not helpful to add a JSFidddle with two divs in HTML, and a CSS solution that doesn't work because it only constrains on one dimension.

Comment: paddings works usually fine, but here you indeed do not need it . flex will do the vertical-alignement fine.

Comment: 2containers only, great, It would , because that's all it is needed, more, would make my kind of answser obsolete :)

Comment: How would flex-box help with constraining a div depending on whether width or height was smaller?

Comment: Show what have you tried and i'll update your CSS ;) (flex for alignement within and around, not sizing)

Comment: Sure - added two solutions, neither work.

Comment: a fork: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bYvLJz , i'll make an answer ;) (calc and vh involved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relay on `calc()` and `vh`/`vw` units among  (`max-`)`width`/`height`.

```css
header {
  background: pink;
  height: 150px;
}
header, .squarred {/* use flex for centering, optionnal */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: ;
}
.squarred {
  width:calc(100vh - 150px);/* luck: header has a fixed height , remove it */
  max-width:100vw;/* stay within the window */
  max-height:100vw;/* stay within the window */
  margin:0 auto;
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;/* can be usefull */
  background:turquoise;
}
html,body {/* set the frame */
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<header><h1>header</h1></header>
<main class="squarred">
  <div class="buffer">
    <h2>I am a square</h2>
    <p>I occupy the remaining space</p>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/MOVQWZ/

Comment: Interesting - accepted it. Can you think of a way without having to have the magic 150px (header size) in there?

Comment: You will need javascript to get header's height on the fly to update square's height , which is better i think anyway ;) Here header's content should not exceed 150px. it can wrap and overflow on small device.